# How to infer generic parameter from mapped type?

Tags: typescript

I use template literal type as keys of a mapped type and I need somehow to infer the generic param to use it for values. Here is the gist of my issue:

```
type EventsMap = {
  // how can I infer SaveKey from `update-${SaveKey}` and pass it to SaveValue<>?
  [K in `update-${SaveKey}`]: (newValue: SaveValue<SaveKey>) => void
}
```

And [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAIgUQGIEECqAZAKgfQGooZoIDKMAvDAN4BQMMAlhCgCYC2DYAXDFAE4BXAKYAaOjADWnFjwDkLQQxayx9ADZCAbkLU8ATAFYxAXxo0oATwAOQmCQCG2gNJCLFSa5AAzXtaHf4ZHRsfEJiEjNLGztHITx7NWEAHicYIQAPKCEwFggY51cAPnco-x9EVExcAiJSAG0nAF1IvxgEbTAoCABZeyt3WnoAeiGYAAsQAHcYYHswGABJRjAvIT58oRc3Lz4QNhgAAwErFnssgFoAEioHAotjA5g5lhgrewg8hlgoEA34xKESUKAH5xA1lodjqcLtdbptXA9GjwABRgISTf7CHhwzGAuFbQoASgoxU0ICUNFMNC8AjAwCgDHAaQ4UHa2SgSQQaUy2VyHgsATZnR6fUKyK07J4CBEMAAdPL7HwAOYQHgABUV9jYQiyfAgnI6XV6VjqCEaROo4lAkBAGllahASuRsiELIZYCVaUNMFkMAA1F72TL5bLFSrCZSzCMYBAJgI1C81rt1mM1rYAEZCWYCCC2DTaNSMPL2GBgARsTN8cSur5CqDOqFnITnfM6FS8QRCQlAA) is the full playground.

Comment: In the playground, where you mention "Should error because the level is a number ...", it is not correct. Your code runs fine, a number would be casted to string when wrapped in backticks, try: `console.log(\`${DEFAULT_VALUES.level}\`)`

Comment: it works in runtime but should fail during typecheck, 
[here](https://t.ly/AOwC) is the updated playground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map the keys independently from the values:

```js
type EventsMap = {
  [K in SaveKey as `update-${K}`]: (newValue: SaveValue<K>) => void
}
```